Resize bar makes my keyboard and mouse not work
I have an MSI tomahawk z390 with an Intel i6 9600k and a 2060 nvidia gpu.
I wanted to try enabling resize bar, but whenever I would go about and do that my keyboard and mouse would shut off and as a result I could not sign in Windows login
*keyboard and mouse work perfectly in bios settings
*when enabling resize bar,  "above 4g decoding/crypto currency mining" also enables automatically and smart fan cpu control disables as well.
*Intel C-State = Disabled | Game Mode = Enabled | XMP = Enabled (maybe there is some inteference)
